# Creating a base contract with (virtual?) base methods that can be overriden

Tags: smart-contract

is there a possibility to create a base contract with methods that can be overridden in contracts that inherits from it?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried anything so far that is not working or is this a general question?

Comment: I tried this situation and it gets crazy with namespaces, or it says that action is already defined etc...
My question would be is this possible at all, are methods in base class supposed to be virtual and maybe if someone can create small example with one method in base class and how it is referenced from inherited? :)

Comment: I guess that this is not supported through the compiler to web assembly (wasm).

Answer (score 1):

I did a fair bit of experimenting and I found a way where inhering within the contract class (sort of) works. Although it doesn't allow for the actions from one contract to be used in another, it does allow the internal functionality.

Below is an example of inheritance used within a smart contract:

### inherited.hpp

```
#ifndef INHERITED
#define INHERITED

#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
using namespace eosio;

class inherited
{
   public:
      ACTION hi2( name nm );
};
#endif
```

### mycontract.hpp

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <inherited.hpp>
using namespace eosio;

CONTRACT mycontract : public inherited, public contract {
   public:
     using contract::contract;
     ACTION hi( name nm );
};
```

### mycontract.cpp

```
#include <mycontract.hpp>
#include <inherited.hpp>

ACTION inherited::hi2( name nm ) {
   /* fill in action body */
   print_f("Name : %\n",nm);
}

ACTION mycontract::hi(name nm){
  eosio::print("Test");
  hi2(nm);
}
```

The ABI generator does not recognise the action `hi2`, but you can use the function within your code without issue.